# Getting subscribers and publishers invoked by a ROS node

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Suppose I have launched a node through a launch file. I would like to get a list of subscribers and a list of publishers that are invoked by that node. What would be the command line to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287775/getting-subscribers-and-publishers-invoked-by-a-ros-node/) by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2018-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
rosnode info your_node_name
```

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2018-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3